# Add a checkbox to a dialog in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am totally new to jQuery and JavaScript and I have to modify some code. I need to add a checkbox to this dialog and take a decision based on the choice. Any suggestions?

```
function deleteFacets()
{
    //  button click
    $("#b_facetsDelete").button().click(function(){
        // selected fIds
        var $fIds=checkSfALOneSelectedFId();
        if(!$fIds)
        {
            return;
        }
        $('#deleteFacetsDialog').dialog('open');        
        return;

    });

    // dialog
    $("#deleteFacetsDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height:160,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            "Delete selected facets": function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');

                // get the selected fIds
                var $fIds=getSfSelectedFIds();

                //update database
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax/ajax_facetsDelete.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {"fIds":$fIds},
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'xml',
                    error: function(){
                        alert('Error loading XML document');
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        //check error
                        var $error=$(data).find('error').text();
                        if($error!="0")
                        {
                            messageBox("Error",$error);
                            return;
                        }
                        //content
                        var $content=$(data).find('content').text();
                        //refresh source facets tab
                        var $srcTabIndex=$("#srcFacetsTab").tabs('option', 'selected');
                        if($content=="0")
                        {
                            messageBox("Succeed!","Delete successfully!");
                            if($srcTabIndex==0)
                            {   // for navigation
                                sfNavRefreshUntilParent();
                            }
                            else if($srcTabIndex==1)
                            {   //for search
                                sfSearchGridRefreshAll();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {                                                       
                            messageBox("Warning!", $content+" can not be deleted since they have child facets or terms. <br/>Please empty them first(Move the child facets and move all the terms).");
                            if($srcTabIndex==0)
                            {   // for navigation (refresh and highlight the invalid fIds)
                                sfNavRefreshWithHighlightFIds($content);
                            }
                            else if($srcTabIndex==1)
                            {   //for search
                                sfSearchGridRefreshWithHighlightFIds($content);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                return; 
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- delete facets confirmation dialog -->
<div id="deleteFacetsDialog" title="Sure to delete?">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These facets will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You will probably need to show us the HTML that goes with this, in particular the section with ID `#deleteFacetsDialog`.

Comment: I've edited it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID that you're calling .dialog on, `deleteFacetsDialog`, is where all the code for the body of the dialog exists. So what you need to do is find that ID in the HTML source and add a checkbox within it (and whatever text / label you need surrounding it).

Then in your delete function callback you can access that checkbox, look up it's value, and do whatever if/else logic you need based on their selection. For example:

```
<div id="deleteFacetsDialog">
...
<label><input type="checkbox" id="permaDelete" />Perminantly delete this facet?</label>
...
</div>
```

And:

```
...
"Delete selected facets": function() {
    ...
    if ($('#permaDelete').is(':checked')) {

    } else {

    }
    ...
}
```

Just make sure the ID you use in the HTML for the input lines up with what you call in JS.

Comment: A final question, where shall I place the last part of the code? The one which I'll put the logic at?

Comment: In the .dialog call, the "Delete selected facets" is part of your existing code. That if goes inside that anonymous function.